# Router SSID not showing up on my Ubuntu / Windows machine, but shows up on every other device in the area

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, ssid

I am trying to connect to a private router in a classroom set up by my professor. This router is a Netgear Nighthawk X6S, model R8000P. It does not show up on my wifi list, but it does show up on my peer's devices as well as my mobile device. I don't think it is an OS problem as I have tried to find it on my Windows system on the same machine and it still does not show up.

I have tried to connect manually via the terminal, but the connection was still refused. It does however work when I connect via Ethernet cable.

I have tried to use an old wireless adapter, but I get the same result.

I am thinking that this is a driver error and I might need to somehow update my network card. I find it strange that it does not give me any problems for any other router I have ever tried accessing. It might be noteworthy to mention that I did connect successfully to this router a year ago, but since then I do not know if it was reset or not.

I am not very familiar with how WiFi broadcasting and channels work, thus I ask for your assistance. Thank you.

**Operating systems:**

- Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
- Windows 10

**Hardware details**

```
description: Notebook
product: Aspire E5-571 (Aspire E5-571)
vendor: Acer
version: V1.32
serial: NXMLTEK06144701B803400
width: 64 bits
capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 smp vsyscall32
configuration: chassis=notebook family=BDW sku=Aspire E5-571 uuid=02A6B6D3-6A31-11E4-AA1F-F0761C39E782


*-core
   description: Motherboard
   product: EA50_HB
   vendor: Acer
   physical id: 0
   version: V1.32
   serial: NBML81100D4476E6713400
   slot: Type2 - Board Chassis Location
 *-firmware
      description: BIOS
      vendor: Insyde Corp.
      physical id: 0
      version: V1.32
      date: 09/15/2015
      size: 128KiB
      capacity: 6MiB
      capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int9keyboard int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
```

**Network details**

```
Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 12)
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1025:0940]
```

Comment: It is most likely that the wireless connection sends through a protocol not supported by your wifi card, such as 5Ghz band or 40 or even 80mhz band. If your wifi card only supports 802.11a/b but not g or ac, and the router is setup to only work on ac, but not a, then you could not connect.

Comment: I second LPChip, what frequency and Wi-Fi Standards do router and devices use?

Comment: @albin, you do? If his wireless card supported wireless-a he would see, and probably be able to connect to the 802.11ac interface. Lpchips comment is all over the place, almost incoherent... There are no 80Mhz bands or 40Mhz bands. He is confusing band with **channel width**. My hope is with these clarifications **you** will also not be confused. Note: he also totally skipped over 802.11N...

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I do, although other causes might be possible as well. More info is required here.

Comment: @albin, what information do you think is required? We have the router model, and the client WLAN adapter model & OS in use. What else would you ask the OP to provide?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I meant the actual configuration that is being used (to make sure he doesn't use different protocols on AP and client), but it seems from the votes your answer is quite extensive, so never mind.

Answer (score 3):

It's most likely a  **hardware capabilities issue**, and **not** a driver issue at all.

I think what lpchip meant to say is:

Newer standards use **20/40/80** and even **160mhz** wide **channels in the 5.8Ghz band**.

This most likely means that your devices are 802.11-b/g/draft-n **20mhz** channel mode only devices.
(They only work on **2.4Ghz with 20Mhz wide channels**)

The original PCI card that came in your laptop is a Atheros WB335, it's a dual WiFi bluetooth card. The Wlan chip on this card is a Atheros AR9565. Unfortunately, **it's capabilities are 802.11-b/g/n over 2.4Ghz with 20Mhz wide channels**.

You could ask the professor to set the 2.4Ghz radio to 20Mhz/40Mhz dynamic channel mode in the router for legacy devices.

Some can't even handle the dynamic mode and need to have the router use 20Mhz static channel mode. It really depends on how old the adapters in question actually are.

My recommendation would be to upgrade your WLAN adapter to a newer standard. 802.11-AC or even the newest 802.11ax will get much better performance than legacy wireless devices. Although depending on your skill level, this may not be an option. You would need to upgrade the antennas in the laptop to hybrid 2.4Ghz/5.8Ghz ones with u.fl connectors. Or go with a new USB adapter.